# Converting Magento to Angular Js

Tags: angular, magento

I have a plan to create a separate mobile site for Magento in angular js4.

Means in tabs and mobile loads the angular site and desktops will load Magento

site.

In that case how will i manage Site Urls ???

Answer (score 0):

url.com //your Site

m.url.com //For the mobile Version

Inside of Magento something like:

```
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)"
 href="http://m.url.com/page-1">
```

With this line you tell at which screensize u want to let the user swap to your mobile site.

Here is an explanation from google: https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls?hl=en